# Search under a AD Group for users members and their department

Tags: powershell

Im trying to export from specific AD groups the members and their respective departments for each one of them.

I have it like this:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "ABC" | 
    Select-Object Name | 
    Sort-Object Name | 
    Export-csv "C:\ABC.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

And it did show me all members, but then I`m trying to do another search under each user as the department is a property only for the members.

Maybe under that look for another search:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * `
    -SearchBase 'ou=abc,ou=Users,dc=corporate,dc=coolguys,dc=org' `
    -Properties Name,Department, EmailAddress |
    select Name,Department, EmailAddress |
    Out-GridView
```

Comment: So, what's your question? How to get each users corresponding department property from the returned users of `Get-ADGroupMember`?

Comment: What if the member is another group? Should it be ignored?

Comment: Not exactly Abraham, as I said if the "ABC" AD group with Powershell I run the command I can export all members, still for each member I would like to see apart from their name or email, I would need their department to be also exported in the csv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a Windows box to test it, but this should do the trick:

```
Get-AdGroupMember "ABC" -Recursive | 
    Get-Aduser -Properties Name,Department, EmailAddress | 
    Select-Object Name,Department, EmailAddress |
    Sort-Object -Property Name | 
    Export-Csv "C:\ABC.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding 'UTF8'
```

If you use `-Recursive`, you should only get objects that are users. If you don't want to use recursive (you're not interested in the members of child groups), then you'd need to slightly alter the code to filter out non-user objects:

```
Get-AdGroupMember "ABC" | 
    Where-Object {$_.objectClass -eq 'User'} |
    Get-Aduser -Properties Name,Department, EmailAddress | 
    Select-Object Name,Department, EmailAddress |
    Sort-Object -Property Name | 
    Export-Csv "C:\ABC.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding 'UTF8'
```

I added `-Encoding 'UTF8'` to the `Export-Csv` call, to make sure you have no character encoding issues in the export file.

Comment: Hello and pardon my ignorance, I am unable to test this but, how would parameter binding work in your `Get-ADUser`. Since `-Filter` is used to find the AD accounts, you're explicitly telling it to  search for everyone, not based on your LHS cmdlet of `Get-ADGroupMember`.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala You're absolutely right, thanks for pointing this out. I modified the code (and was able to test it).

Comment: Hello and thank you for trying, unfortunately, is not working,as I`ve tested seems that is searching and pulling all users from everywhere but not from the specific AD group called group "ABC".  Also in the end it gives the error :  Get-Aduser : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take 
pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:2 char:5
+     Get-Aduser -Filter * `

Comment: First verify that `Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "ABC"` is giving you the correct results. If that isn't showing you the members you're expecting, then you're not pointing to the correct group. Also, make sure whether you want to use `-Recursive` or not, as it will go through all of the child groups and return those members as well.

Comment: Thank you ƘɌỈSƬƠƑ - now it worked as expected! Much appreciated your help.